# Unresolved variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been learning a tutorial on creating file upload, there is an error with the "unresolved variable total_line" in the index.php even though the `total_line` is declared in another php file : The variable is then being called under `data.total_line`.

The code below is the files where I get the total_line variable and where I create the upload file webpage.

```js
if (isset($_POST['hidden_field'])) {
  $error = '';
  $total_line = '';
  session_start();
  if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {
    $allowed_extension = array('csv');
    $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($file_array);
    if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) {
      $new_file_name = rand().
      '.'.$extension;
      $_SESSION['csv_file_name'] = $new_file_name;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'file/'.$new_file_name);
      $file_content = file('file/'.$new_file_name, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      $total_line = count($file_content);
    } else {
      $error = 'Only CSV file format is allowed';
    }
  } else {
    $error = 'Please Select File';
  }

  if ($error != '') {
    $output = array(
      'error' => $error
    );
  } else {
    $output = array(
      'success' => true,
      'total_line' => ($total_line - 1)
    );
  }

  echo json_encode($output);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Import CSV File Data</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Import CSV File Data with Progress Bar </h1>
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Import CSV File Data</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <span id="message"></span>
        <form id="sample_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select CSV File</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="import" id="import" class="btn btn-info" value="Import" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-group" id="process" style="display:none;">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
              <span id="process_data">0</span> - <span id="total_data">0</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var clear_timer;

    $('#sample_form').on('submit', function(event) {
      $('#message').html('');
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('#import').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $('#import').val('Importing');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.success) {
            $('#total_data').text(data.total_line);

            start_import();

            clear_timer = setInterval(get_import_data, 2000);

            $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">CSV File Uploaded</div>');
          }
          if (data.error) {
            $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.error + '</div>');
            $('#import').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#import').val('Import');
          }
        }
      })
    });

    function start_import() {
      $('#process').css('display', 'block');
      $.ajax({
        url: "import.php",
        success: function() {

        }
      })
    }

    function get_import_data() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        success: function(data) {
          var total_data = $('#total_data').text();
          var width = Math.round((data / total_data) * 100);
          $('#process_data').text(data);
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', width + '%');
          if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(clear_timer);
            $('#process').css('display', 'none');
            $('#file').val('');
            $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Data Successfully Imported</div>');
            $('#import').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#import').val('Import');
          }
        }
      })
    }

  });
</script>
```

The execution of the file results in the [image] and nothing else is happening.

This is the screenshot of the error:
[image: Error image]

Comment: If you declare a variable in another php-file it is not automatically included in the php file you are using. If you want the value of $total_line included you have to include that other file with require() or include().

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld , data.total_line should be able to call the variable from another PHP file and I followed the tutorial from : https://www.webslesson.info/2019/11/csv-import-using-ajax-progress-bar-in-php.html

Comment: Do you see any other errors in the browser console? Is this error referring to this line: `$('#total_data').text(data.total_line);`?

Comment: On the intellij program, the only highlighted error is this line, @El_Vanja

Comment: @El_Vanja, it's weird because when I compiled, the compilation says no error but couldn't upload the file for some reason

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error you showed is not coming from code explicit, but from insufficient comments in WebStorm. Your IDE doesn't know where it should look for structure of your Object data, because it gets it through Ajax.

You can use something similar to let your IDE know that variable `data` has 2 possible parameters. It's JSDoc.

```
/**
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {boolean} data.success
 * @param {number} data.total_line
 */
```

It will hide popup with warning, but it is not the cause that your program is not working. You should show output in Console to show what is result of Javascript code.